# Removing four of a king

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing code for a GoFish game and everytime I get four of a kind I get an out of bounds error.

Here is what I have. I need to find four and then remove it. What I am trying to do with this code is go through each card and check if there is four of it in my hand.

```
int c = 0;

for (int k = 0; k < hand.size(); k++) {
    c = 0;
    for (int z = 0; z < hand.size(); z++) {
        if(hand.get(k).getRank().equalsIgnoreCase(hand.get(z).getRank())) {
            c++;
            if (c==4) {
                for(int m = z; z > m-4; z-- ) {
                    hand.remove(m);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use: `if (c==3)` —— `0, 1, 2, 3` <-- 4 values

Comment: You can ask a better question than that! What language? Which index appears to give a problem `k`, `z` or `m` ?

Comment: Java. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Looking at the exception trace in the console should tell you which line and function call threw the exception.

Comment: @JamesP your innermost `for`-loop is a bit odd. You initialize `m`, compare and decrement `z`, and then use `m` (which hasn't changed) to remove a card from the hand. Is this intended?